# Renaming AD user object name in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am trying to get only AD Objects of type user and then iterate over all them and change AD user object name. So I have done below:

```
$Users = Get-ADObject -Filter {(ObjectClass -eq "user")} # OR Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user"'

$Users | foreach
{
    # Here code to create name based on conditions ($newUserObjectName)
    Rename-ADObject -Identity $_ -NewName $newUserObjectName
}
```

The problem is that Get-ADObject is returning not only users but also computer objects.... I only want user object classes. Also I am not sure If below line of code is correct by setting identity to $_ in order to update the current user in the iteration:

```
Rename-ADObject -Identity $_ -NewName $newUserObjectName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Get-ADUser instead of Get-ADObject and just return the DistinguishedName? Obviously, DON'T just run this code :)

```
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter *).DistinguishedName #This gets all the users in AD
Foreach($user in $users){
    Rename-ADObject -Identity $user -NewName $newUserObjectName
}
```

Comment: Of course, I know, don't run this code as this will try to put the same object name for all user objects :). This is the idea, how to retrieve all the users using Get-ADUser and then rename user object found using Rename-ADObject.

Answer (score 2):

The `Computer` objectClass is derived from the `User` objectClass. Hence, queries for user class will return both `Computers` and `Users`. If you want to filter for Users only, you have to specify `ObjectCategory` as `Person`

```
$Users = Get-ADObject -Filter {(Objectclass -eq "user") -and (objectCategory -eq "Person")}
```

Use that or you can use the goodole `Get-ADuser`

Comment: I did not know computer objectClass was deriving from the User objectClass so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ADUser` and `Set-ADUser`:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
$Users | foreach {
    # Naming code
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -SamAccountName $newName
}
```

This replaces all user's identities to `$newName`.

Note you can replace `-SamAccountName` with any other property of an `ADUser`. for example if you want to replace the display name instead, you would use `-Name $newName`